# Orden con Left Join

Tags: mysql

Saludos a todos realizando un query viene a mí una cuestión he visto que el orden como se hace un **LEFT JOIN** varia, ahora bien normalmente se hace así:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla_1 LEFT JOIN tabla_2 ON tabla_1.tabla2_id = tabla_2.id
```

por decirlo de alguna manera es lo mas convencional o tradicional encontrarlo de dicha manera, pero también existe la otra variante:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla_1 LEFT JOIN tabla_2 ON tabla_2.id = tabla_1.tabla2_id
```

Como podemos notar luego de **ON**  varia el orden de la primera sentencia con respecto a la segunda.

**La pregunta**

Infiere en algo este orden en un **LEFT JOIN** ?

Comment: No, el orden es importante cuando estás indicando el join, es decir: tabla1 left join tabla2 es distinto a tabla2 left join tabla1.

Comment: Además de lo escrito por @zerocool, esta imagen siempre me ha resultado ilustrativa. https://proxy.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FKB%2Fdatabase%2FVisual_SQL_Joins%2FVisual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg&f=1

Comment: no, modificar el orden en el `ON` no tiene ninguna influencia en la sentencia ni en los resultados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El orden que infiere es el de las tablas en el join ya que teniendo en cuenta la siguiente data:

```
create table tabla_1(
 id integer,
 nombre varchar(100)
);

create table tabla_2(
 id integer,
 id_tabla1 integer,
 nombre varchar(100)
);

insert into tabla_1 values (1,'pedro');
insert into tabla_2 values (1, 1,'martinez');
insert into tabla_2 values (2, 3,'rodriguez');
```

Que la puedes ver acá: [Sql Fiddle, build -> run sql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f952c5/8)

Si ejecutamos:

```
select * from tabla_1 t1 left join tabla_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_tabla1;
```

Veremos que la salida es:

```
id | nombre | id | id_tabla1 | nombre
```

Si ejecutamos inviertiendo el orden del join:

```
select * from tabla_2 t2 left join tabla_1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id_tabla1;
```

Nos cambia la salida a:

```
id | id_tabla1 | nombre | id | nombre
```

Acá resulta obvio el por qué ya que primero esta tabla1 luego tabla2 (se muestran las columnas en ese orden y en la segunda ejecución cambian).

La cosa es que no es esto lo importante del orden, sino que tenemos que tener en cuenta la teoría de conjuntos (en la que se basan los joins de SQL) debido a que cuando indicamos que la tabla1 tendra un left join con la tabla2 decimos que seleccionaremos todos los registros de la tabla1 (tabla a la izquierda) más los registros de la tabla derecha que se relacionen con la misma. Dicho en teoria de conjunto tomaremos los elementos del conjunto de la izquierda más los de la derecha que se intersectan:

```
(A ∩ B) ∪ A
```

[image: Joins]

Por lo  que, de nuevo, al ejecutar el query:

```
select * from tabla_1 t1 left join tabla_2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_tabla1
```

La salida sería:

```
id | nombre | id | id_tabla1 | nombre
1  | pedro  | 1  | 1         | martinez
```

Resultado esperado ya que seleccionamos todos los registros de la tabla_1 (que es uno solo) más los registros de la tabla_2 donde se intersecta con la tabla_1 (uno solo también porque tabla_2.id_tabla1 tiene el id del único registro de la tabla_1), por ende una sola fila es retornada.

Ahora al invertir el orden del join ejecutando el query:

```
select * from tabla_2 t2 left join tabla_1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id_tabla1
```

La salida del mismo es:

```
id | id_tabla1 | nombre    | id    | nombre
1  | 1         | martinez  | 1     | pedro
2  | 3         | rodriguez |(null) | (null)
```

De nuevo acá el orden de las columnas no es lo importante sino que nos trae otra fila, teniendo en cuenta lo explicado con anterioridad: *"seleccionaremos todos los registros de la tabla1 (tabla a la izquierda) más los registros de la tabla derecha que se relacionen con la misma."*, además de que en éste caso la tabla_1 (izquierda) es ahora la tabla_2, nos trae dos registros de la tabla_2 (izquierda), más un registro de la tabla_1 (derecha) que se intersecta.

Notarás que la segunda fila no trae resultados en las columnas de la tabla_1 (derecha), ya que para el segundo registro no existe un elemento (fila) que se intersecte pero como la consulta debe traer todos los de la izquierda entonces trae las columnas de la tabla_2 y las columnas de la tabla_1 las deja en null.

Ésto es útil en situaciones donde queremos consultar por ejemplo el listado de clientes y sus productos adquiridos, pero que si un cliente no tenga productos igual lo retorne la consulta, el query sería:

```
select nombre from clientes c left join productos p on c.id = p.id_cliente
```

O también si queremos buscar los clientes sin productos:

```
select nombre from clientes c left join productos p on c.id = p.id_cliente and p.id is null
```

Saludos.

Comment: Saludos @zerocool sin duda una muy buena explicación y bien detallada, gracias..!!

Answer (score 0):

NO influye en nada el orden de las sentencias después de ON, es decir, ambas sentencias que escribiste son correctas. 
En lo que sí influye es en el orden de las tablas que se encuentras antes y después de LEFT pues de ello dependerá cuál tabla será la "tabla base" para la unión LEFT.