# LEFT JOIN con valores duplicados (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

La **data** de mi **BD** (la tabla enfriadores, dispensadores, chatarra, fountain, maquinas tienen la misma estructura, he puesto la de dispensadores)

```
//tabla dispensadores
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dispensadores` (
`id_dispensador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_solicitud` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `si_no` varchar(10),
  `total_dispensador` int(100)
);


//tabla solicitudes
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `solicitudes` (
`id_solicitud` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `proveedor` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_sucursal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`status_sucursal` varchar(255)
);

ALTER TABLE `dispensadores`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_dispensador`);
ALTER TABLE `solicitudes`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_solicitud`);

INSERT INTO `solicitudes` (`id_solicitud`, `proveedor`, `id_sucursal`, `status_sucursal`) VALUES
(3, 'AIR XALAPA', 3, 'Cerrada');

INSERT INTO `dispensadores` (`id_dispensador`, `id_solicitud`, `si_no`, `total_dispensador`) VALUES
(1, 3 , 'Si', 100);
```

La siguiente **Query** me suma incorrectamente, lo que está pasando es que duplica el valor, si mi total debería ser de 150 en el resultado muestra 300

```
SELECT sol.id_solicitud, sol.proveedor, sol.id_sucursal, 
       sol.fecha_solicitud, sol.status, sol.fecha_solicitud, 
       sol.fecha_recoleccion, sol.tiempo_retiro, 
       SUM(enf.total_enfriador) as total_enfriador, 
       SUM(maq.total_maquina) as total_maquina, 
       SUM(dis.total_dispensador) as total_dispensador, 
       SUM(fou.total_fountain) as total_fountain,cha.si_no, sol.status_sucursal 
FROM   solicitudes sol
LEFT JOIN enfriadores enf ON sol.id_solicitud = enf.id_solicitud 
LEFT JOIN maquinas maq ON sol.id_solicitud = maq.id_solicitud
LEFT JOIN fountain fou ON sol.id_solicitud = fou.id_solicitud    
LEFT JOIN dispensadores dis ON sol.id_solicitud = dis.id_solicitud
LEFT JOIN chatarra cha ON sol.id_solicitud = cha.id_solicitud 
WHERE  sol.id_solicitud = 3 
AND    sol.status_sucursal = 'Cerrada'
GROUP BY sol.id_solicitud, sol.id_sucursal;
```

Comment: Hola indira, colocanos la data de prueba para determinar el error en la consulta. Te dejo una pregunta en la que explico un poco como trabajan los left joins mientras tanto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250121/orden-con-left-join/250573?noredirect=1#comment465755_250573

Comment: He agregado la data @zerocool, funciona bien cuando solo tengo un registro, cuando agrego otro es cuando se doglega la suma

Comment: La suma no se [doblega](https://dle.rae.es/?id=E2Twtx8), sino que se [duplica](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EH3Z0pB), ¿verdad?

Comment: Si, ya actualizo, esta mal planteado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es de concepto de cómo funciona la operación *join* y luego la agrupación. Ocurre que al hacer *join* con distintas tablas, supongamos que una solicitud tiene un enfriador y dos dispensadores, en ambas *tuplas* va a *repetirse* el valor de `total_enfriador`, por lo que la suma va a ser incorrecta.

Si esa solicitud tuviese dos enfriadores y dos dispensadores, entonces ambos datos saldrían duplicados.

Prueba primero hacer solo los *joins*, sin `group by` y verás a lo que me refiero.

Para tener una suma independiente de cada uno, podrías resolverlo de varias maneras.

1. Con sub-consultas:

   ```
   SELECT   sol.id_solicitud
          , sol.proveedor
          , sol.id_sucursal
          , sol.fecha_solicitud
          , sol.status
          , sol.fecha_solicitud
          , sol.fecha_recoleccion
          , sol.tiempo_retiro
          , (select SUM(enf.total_enfriador) from enfriadores enf where enf.id_solicitud = sol.id_solicitud) as total_enfriador
          , (select SUM(maq.total_maquina) from maquinas maq where maq.id_solicitud = sol.id_solicitud) as total_maquina
          , (select SUM(dis.total_dispensador) from dispensadores dis where dis.id_solicitud = sol.id_solicitud) as total_dispensador
          , (select SUM(fou.total_fountain) from fountain fou where fou.id_solicitud = sol.id_solicitud) as total_fountain
     FROM solicitudes sol
    WHERE sol.id_solicitud = 3 
      AND sol.status_sucursal = 'Cerrada'
   ```
2. Con CTE's que resumen la información por solicitud, si tienes muchos datos y trabajas en una versión moderna del motor, que soporta la sintaxis, esto va a ser más eficiente:

   ```
   with
   Enf as (
   select   id_solicitud
          , SUM(total_enfriador) total_enfriador
     from enfriadores
    group by id_solicitud
   )
   ,
   Maq as (
   select   id_solicitud
          , SUM(total_maquina) total_maquina
     from maquinas
    group by id_solicitud
   )
   ,
   Dis as (
   select   id_solicitud
          , SUM(total_dispensador) total_dispensador
     from dispensadores
    group by id_solicitud
   )
   ,
   Fou as (
   select   id_solicitud
          , SUM(total_fountain) total_fountain
     from fountain
    group by id_solicitud
   )
   SELECT   sol.id_solicitud
          , sol.proveedor
          , sol.id_sucursal
          , sol.fecha_solicitud
          , sol.status
          , sol.fecha_solicitud
          , sol.fecha_recoleccion
          , sol.tiempo_retiro
          , enf.total_enfriador
          , maq.total_maquina
          , dis.total_dispensador
          , fou.total_fountain
     FROM solicitudes sol
          left join Enf on Enf.id_solicitud = sol.id_solicitud
          left join Maq on Maq.id_solicitud = sol.id_solicitud
          left join Dis on Dis.id_solicitud = sol.id_solicitud
          left join Fou on Fou.id_solicitud = sol.id_solicitud
    WHERE sol.id_solicitud = 3 
      AND sol.status_sucursal = 'Cerrada'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

La totalización de las columnas que quieres sumar termina siendo afectada por los registros que tengan las demás columnas que quieres sumar y que referencias vía left join.

Que tal poner estas comuna calculadas como consultas independientes?

Ej:

```
SELECT sol.id_solicitud, sol.proveedor, sol.id_sucursal,
(select SUM(dis.total_dispensador) from dispensadores dis  where sol.id_solicitud = dis.id_solicitud ) as total_dispensador
    FROM   solicitudes sol
WHERE  sol.id_solicitud = 3 
AND    sol.status_sucursal = 'Cerrada'
GROUP BY sol.id_solicitud, sol.id_sucursal;
```