# LEFT JOIN con duplicidad de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, sql, join

trataré de ser breve con este problema:

Tengo 3 tablas

#### TABLA [A]

```
| Id | Valor_A |
|--------------|
| 1  | Valor 1 |
| 2  | Valor 2 |
```

#### TABLA [B]

```
| Id | Id_Tabla_A |
|-----------------|
| 1  | 1          |
| 2  | 1          |
```

#### TABLA [C]

```
| Id | Id_Tabla_B | Valor_C |
|-----------------|---------|
| 1  | 1          | MiValor |
```

y estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta

```
select a.Id, a.Valor_A, c.Valor_C
from Tabla_A as a
  left join Tabla_B as b on b.Id_Tabla_A = a.Id
  left join Tabla_C as c on c.Id_Tabla_B = b.Id and c.Valor_C = 'MiValor';
```

Mi resultado deseado es:

```
| Id | Valor_A | Valor_C |
|----|---------|---------|
| 1  | Valor 1 | MiValor |
| 2  | Valor 2 | NULL    |
```

Sin embargo obtengo este resultado

```
| Id | Valor_A | Valor_C |
|----|---------|---------|
| 1  | Valor 1 | MiValor |
| 1  | Valor 1 | NULL    |
| 2  | Valor 2 | NULL    |
```

Por cuestiones de datos no es posible cambiar el último **left join** con un **inner join** debido a que es requerido que muestre la fila con el **Valor 2**.

**IMPORTANTE**
Puedo obtener este resultado mediante un left join (select), pero esta consulta
se convertirá en una vista (VIEW), en SQL Server es válido, pero hacer un left join (select) sobre otro motor de base de datos no es permitido.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres es *agregar* las filas resultantes con el fin de presentar **una sola fila** para cada elemento de la Tabla A. Para esto tienes que usar `GROUP BY`.

Por ejemplo:

```
select a.Id, max(a.Valor_A) as Valor_A, max(c.Valor_C) as Valor_C
from Tabla_A as a
left join Tabla_B as b on b.Id_Tabla_A = a.Id
left join Tabla_C as c on c.Id_Tabla_B = b.Id and c.Valor_C = 'MiValor'
group by a.Id
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo ejecutándose en [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ponVyBYQgoT8cqgKV44vTP/1).

Comment: efectivamente, el query real era mucho mas complejo, no se me había ocurrido hacer un max, sin embargo si estaba usando el **group by** , pero de manera errónea, duda resuelta, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Es simple, al hacer un LEFT JOIN traes todos los datos de la tabla A y al relacionarlos con la tabla B existe un valor que se repite 2 veces y es por este que estas haciendo la relación, lo que significa que el valor 1 existe 2 veces en la tabla B y el 2 que nunca existe, pero se muestra en el resultado. El resultado de mostrar todas las columnas de tu tabla queda mas o menos así:

```
ID          ValorA               ID          ID_Tabla_A  ID          ID_Tabla_B  ValorC
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
1           Valor 1              1           1           NULL        NULL        NULL
1           Valor 1              2           1           NULL        NULL        NULL
2           Valor 2              NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Como padres ver, Valor 1 re repite las mismas veces que ID_Tabla_A por la relación y existencia de información.

Saludos.

Comment: Revisa este post si tienes dudas https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/250121/orden-con-left-join

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo, pero tal vez no fui muy explícito, quería ver si me ayudaban con otro punto de vista para llegar al resultado que no fuera un left join con subquery ```left join (select .. from ... ) as x on x.field = y.field ```